# Custom JSON Serialization in order to save reduce data being transferred

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We all love the JSON format. It saves a lots of bytes comparing to XML files. That's one of the reason why it became so popular.

Now I'd like to squeeze a little bit more juice of that and return a even smaller JSON file from the server.

Considering that my data would be bound to a grid on the front-end with that format

```
 id     a   b   c
key1    1   2   3
key2    4   5   6
key3    7   8   9
```

We would probably return a JSON on the following format:

```
{data: [
    { "id": "key1", "a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3" },
    { "id": "key2", "a": "4", "b": "5", "c": "6" },
    { "id": "key3", "a": "7", "b": "8", "c": "9" },
]}
```

As you see, we are repeating the column names for each row.

What if the JSON had this format below?

```
{
    "meta": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "data": 
    {
        "key1": ["1", "2", "3"],
        "key2": ["4", "5", "6"],
        "key3": ["7", "8", "9"]
    }
}
```

If we had a hundred of these rows, we could save a substantial amount of bytes.

Q: Is there a custom JSON.net serializer that does that? Or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that on your own, however, as an alternative approach you could gzip your response which is probably doing an even better job in regards to the response size.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to implement it on your own if it is really necessary.

Anyway, there are some other options to reduce your serialized JSON size that are supported by JSON.NET as explained here : [Reducing Serialized JSON Size](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm).

To summarize, you can reduce JSON size by :

1. Not including unnecessary model properties in the serialized JSON result by using `JsonIgnoreAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute`
2. Removing unnecessary spaces and line breaks by using `Formatting.None`
3. Not including properties having null value in the serialized JSON result by using `NullValueHandling.Ignore`
4. Not including properties having default value in the serialized JSON
   result by using `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`
5. Including only specific set of properties in the serialized JSON result by using custom implementation of `IContractResolver` interface

Comment: Thank you. I'll try these options. Cheers!